# How to remove duplicates from a List<List<T>> for value types T?

Tags: c#, linq

This is such a simple question it must surely have been asked and answered already ... but I can't find it.

I want to use LINQ to remove duplicates from a list of lists of value types.  I have tried the following:

```
List<List<int>> a = new List<List<int>>() { new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }, new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }, new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4 } };
// remove duplicates from a
List<List<int>> b = a.Distinct().ToList(); // this doesn't do it
List<List<int>> c = a.Distinct(new ListKeyComparer<int>()).ToList(); // nor does this

internal class ListKeyComparer<TKey> : IEqualityComparer<List<TKey>>
{
  public bool Equals(List<TKey> key1, List<TKey> key2)
  {
    return String.Join("_", key1).Equals(String.Join("_", key2));
  }

  public int GetHashCode(List<TKey> key)
  {
    return key.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

All solutions welcome!

Comment: Could you describe the exact algorithm you want to get at? For example which list has priority when a duplicate is found, the first one? [[1,2,3],[1,4,5]] should return [[2,3],[1,4,5]] or [[1,2,3],[4,5]]?

Comment: Or do you want list with exact identical items removed? does the order count?... As you can see, we need more info :)

Comment: I think your understanding of removing duplicates from a collection is wrong. You're thinking of the scenario where you have `List<int> {1,2,2,3,3}` which `a.Distinct()` would give you back a distinct list. What you actually have is a list of lists, yes each list might contain the number 1, but since each list within the list isn't exactly the same they are in fact distinct to begin with!

Comment: Perhaps have a look at the [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) -Extensions

Comment: Thanks all for your time -- the answers below have done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that it uses the `straight` `GetHashCode` of the `key` list. You can fix it by replacing it with the hash code of a "key string" that you have constructed by joining the numbers with underscores, or by computing the hash code on the fly:

```
// Here is a fix to your method. It would work if TKey values
// cannot have underscores. In any event, it will be very slow.
internal class ListKeyComparer<TKey> : IEqualityComparer<List<TKey>>
{
  // Make a method that produces the key to avoid repeating yourself:
  private string MakeKey(List<TKey> key) {
    return String.Join("_", key);
  }
  public bool Equals(List<TKey> key1, List<TKey> key2)
  {
    return MakeKey(key1).Equals(MakeKey(key2));
  }

  public int GetHashCode(List<TKey> key)
  {
    return MakeKey(key).GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Here is a better implementation:

```
internal class ListKeyComparer<TKey> : IEqualityComparer<List<TKey>>
{
  public bool Equals(List<TKey> key1, List<TKey> key2)
  {
    return key1.SequenceEqual(key2);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(List<TKey> key)
  {
    return key.Aggregate((p, v) => 31*p + v.GetHashCode());
  }
}
```

This implementation is better for three reasons:

- **It is more readable** - Each method is a single line, which is more or less self-explanatory (assuming that you are familiar with computing hash codes of multipart keys)
- **It is more efficient** - This code avoids constructing strings that would be thrown away repeatedly in the process of hashing your keys
- **It improves correctness** - This implementation works correctly even when `TKey` strings include underscores.

The implementation uses LINQ methods [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to shorten the code of `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Excellent -- thank you very much.  In fact I used a simpler GetHashCode() function, namely `return String.Join("_", key).GetHashCode();` as I didn't fully understand yours; it seems to work.

Comment: @EdGraham That's a pretty poor idea.  I would *strongly* discourage you form using that solution, as it has quite a number of fairly profound negative consequences, both in correctness as well as performance.

Comment: @Servy -- care to elaborate?

Comment: @EdGraham I elaborated in detail in my answer, describing multiple ways in which that solution can result in the improper result.

Comment: @EdGraham Take a look at the edit: I elaborated on what I wrote in the comment to the first implementation.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is an `IEqualityComparer` for sequences.  This is not particularly difficult.  (Note that you can trivailly generalize the example to be generic, rather than specific to `int`, and to use `IEnumerable` rather than `List`, as you need no list specific functionally.

```
public class SequenceComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T> comparer;
    public SequenceComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y, comparer);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 19;
            foreach (var item in sequence)
                hash = hash * 79 + comparer.GetHashCode(item);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Equals` comes for free for you in the form of `SequenceEqual`.  The only remaining interesting thing to do is create a meaningful hash based on *the values in the sequence* rather than using the `GetHashCode` method that the sequence provides itself, because it generally won't do that (most any `IEnumerable`, including `List`, will base their hash code on the reference to the class, not the values in it).

In this case, there is no need to provide this `SequenceComparer` with an inner comparer for the types of the items (in this case, `int`) because the default equality should be exactly what you need.  If you had, say, a `List<List<string>>` and you wanted to compare the lists for equality and do a case insensitive comparison of the strings, then you could use a `new SequenceComparer<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Note that concatting the string values of the items is not a particularly safe means of comparing two sequences.  The objects may not have meaningful `ToString` methods.  (Any type that doesn't override `ToString` will just print out the type name, meaning everything will be equal to everything else.)  You also need to deal with cases of collisions.  For example, if you had one item that generated a string value of `"1_2"` that would be considered equal to two different items each generating `"1"` and `"2"`.

Comment: Great stuff, Servy: thanks a lot for the explanation about hash codes and collisions as well.  I marked the other answer as the official one but I appreciate that yours is equally valid.